# COM+ invoking method in remote instance Unknown name error

Tags: c#, .net, com, remoting

I have a COM dll which I was using in my .net project through interop referance. Now I got a requirement to move this COM component to another remote machine and create instance there.(kind of out of machine similar to out of process, probably this is remoting, i don't know :-))

What I have done was created a new COM+ applciation in server machine. Added this component inside this app. This is how it is listed in COM+ interface on server.
[image]

Exported this app as proxy insatller and installed in my client machine. Used following code to
access this

```
Type type;
type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DllName.COMName", "serverName", false);
var COMObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var returnValue = COMObject.GetType().InvokeMember("Method_1",   BindingFlags.Public |  BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, COMObject, new object[1] { "1" });
```

But I am getting UNKNOWN NAME (0x80020006) error when invoking Method_1? Have any one face similar issue before, please help me.

Comment: Why use the System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance flags? Should be InvokeMethod instead.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was using BindingFlags.InvokeMethod only. Still same error

Comment: Have you tried to 1) define the ISomeInterfaceName interface in C# (with a Guid attribute corresponding to IID_ISomeInterfaceName and the 3 methods), 2) cast COMObject to this interface, and 3) call Method2 on this interface.

Comment: Does this GUID needs to be same as that of CLSID of component in remote server or something?

Comment: No, it must be the same as the IID (interface ID) of the ISomeInterfaceName

Comment: This worked to some extend,I and getting remote procedure call error now. In my server machine I am getting an error in event logs faulting applciation dllhost.exe. faulting module kernel32.dll

Comment: Hmm... sounds bad! you'll need to investigate more, or you created a wrong interface definition in C# that doesn't match the COM one.

Comment: Your suggestion helped me to answer my original question. Current error is something specific to my app I guess. I could see bits and pieces of internal details of my component in server event vwr. Would you please resubmit that comment with 3 steps as an answer so that I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is this:

1) create an equivalent interface in C#, something like this:

```
[Guid("<the interface IID goes here>")]
public interface ISomeInterfaceName
{
   int Method1(...);
   int Method2(...);
   int Method3(...);
   ...
}
```

2) and then this, instead of your initial late-binding code:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DllName.COMName", "serverName", false);
var COMObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var if = (ISomeInterfaceName)COMObject;
if.Method1(...);
```

NOTES: the IID must the IID from the interface, not to be confused with the CLSID. The methods should be laid out to correspond exactly to the COM ones (the methods order is important, how parameters and return type are defined is also important)

You could also [import the TLB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from the COM component, if you have a lot of classes and intefaces like this.

Comment: @Simon Mourier, One of the method is returning a string. But when implemented this way its always returning null. Any idea why?

Comment: @Shanadas - your method definition in C# is probably incorrect. It does not match the COM one. You may also check the PreserveSigAttribute custom attribute.

Comment: I rechecked, method definition is correct only also included PreserveSigAttribute , still i am getting null return value

Comment: @Shanadas - difficult to say w/o any piece of code. Have you also checked MarshalAs attributes on string parameters? Otherwise, you should ask another question with detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use GetType() when invoking the method. `COMObject.InvokeMember()` should be sufficient.

Also, try getting the Type from the ClassID - by using `.GetTypeFromCLSID()` - rather than ProgID.

Additionally rather than `BindingFlags.Public` use `BindingFlags.Default`. This will specify that all type members will be available.

Comment: @hugh - COM does not support "static" methods :-)

Comment: Method_1 is not a static method

Answer (score 0):

If you have your application proxy correctly installed and configured in the client machine you should be able to instantiate your COM+ just as you create any other object instance.

Try just this:

```
IMyExpectedInterface o = new MyCOMServicedComponent();
o.SomeMethod();
```

If that is not running fine let me know the exception result you get while instantiating it.

Comment: COM+ proxy is installed fine in my machine. Do I need to add assembly referance, so as to make the above code work?

Comment: Are both machines in the same domain?

Comment: Yes, both are in same domain.