# COM+ Invocation error code on remote machine

Tags: c#, com-interop, com+, typelib

I have a new requirement to change the way we reference a COM+ object.
Before it was fine to add it through the Add References and find the COM object from the list though the `TypeLib` name.

This has now been changed and I am trying to figure out how can I create an instance using the Activator.CreateInstance.

So far, I have the following:

```
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DllName.COMName", "serverName", false);
var comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

When invoking the method

```
comObject.GetType().InvokeMember("MyMethod",   BindingFlags.Public |  BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, COMObject, new object[1] { "12345" });
```

I get an `UNKNOWN NAME (0x80020006)` during the invocation when the code is executed on the **remote machine**, 
...however on the development machine, the call passes without any problem. On the remote machine it logs the exception! It drives me crazy.

I found this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/822335, but I dont think it is relevant to me.

Both COM+ interface names are identical in both machines and I have ran out of options. Has anyone faced the same issue with 2 different machines?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why are you using reflection instead of interop? You *can* add a reference to the type library, instantiate strongly typed object and call `MyMethod` on it directly

Comment: Besides, if you google for the error number and message, you'll find [this probably duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107747/com-invoking-method-in-remote-instance-unknown-name-error). COM/COM+ works through interfaces. Multiple classes can support a single interface. The *class* itself doesn't expose any members, you have to request a specific interface to call a method on it.

Comment: ok will have a look at their suggestions. could it be permissions issue on the COM+?

Comment: No. That would be an ACCESS_DENIED message. What you tried to do simply isn't possible with COM/COM+. You *can't* call a method on the class, you need to ask for an interface first. You are probably confused by the "default" interfaces used in VB6/VB.NET - specially named interfaces that the VB compiler would call if no other interface was specified (by casting). There was nothing default about them, it was simply compiler magic